# What is the intent of this IE-conditional hack?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

Can you tell me what is supposed to happen for IE browsers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if lt IE 9]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en" dir="ltr"><![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
...
```

I can understand that non-IE browsers would only interpret:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
```

but the condition for greater than IE8 isn't making a lot of sense:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> ... <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Is this a hack?  The notations for opening and closing comments don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra `!--` bits are there to make it a valid HTML comment so that validators don't complain about bogus comments. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490727/creating-valid-conditional-comments-for-stylesheets-without-a-bogus-comment-v/17492107#17492107) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405858/is-there-a-new-standard-for-html-commenting/29406176#29406176). What non-IE browsers really see are two regular HTML comments containing `[if gt IE 8]><!` and `<![endif]` respectively.

The conditional comments allow greater than IE8 to see that `<html>` tag. As you've correctly pointed out, non-IE browsers will also consume that same `<html>` tag — the `!--` bits are what allow them to do so. I wouldn't call it a hack, but then again, conditional comments *themselves* might be a hack depending on whom you ask (I certainly don't think so).

Comment: Thanks, it was difficult trying to search for "<!-->".